# Hudson -- create users

Tags: authentication, continuous-integration, hudson

I was hoping if there was an easy way to create Hudson users, so they are required to log in.

And if they are not logged in they are only able to view build statuses. Nothing else.

Please and thank you

Comment: Have a look here: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Standard+Security+Setup

Answer (score 4):

From the main hudson page:

- Click on Manage Hudson on the left
- Click on Configure System
- Check Enable Security
- Set up your users and Permissions!

You can use Matrix-based security to give specific users certain permissions, and then use the "Anonymous" row for those not logged on.